# How to remove specific elements from array in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to use filter on my function, but I have a little problem.

So, I have this response, here I want to filter by "NAVE"

```
[
     {
         "codicePat": 93009428,
         "dataInizioAttivita": "1992-03-01",
         "dataCessazione": "0001-01-01",
         "descrizioneTipoCertificato": "NAVE",
     },
     {
         "codicePat": 93009429,
         "dataInizioAttivita": "1992-07-01",
         "dataCessazione": "0001-01-01",
         "descrizioneTipoCertificato": "NAVE",
     },
     {
         "codicePat": 93009430,
         "dataInizioAttivita": "1997-04-03",
         "dataCessazione": "0001-01-01",
         "descrizioneTipoCertificato": "COMANDATA",
 
     },
     {
         "codicePat": 93009431,
         "dataInizioAttivita": "1992-09-01",
         "dataCessazione": "1997-06-08",
         "descrizioneTipoCertificato": "NAVE",
     }
]
```

I'm using this function:

```
if(tipo === x.descrizioneTipoCertificato){
     const index = dataPan.content.findIndex(obj => {
           return obj.descrizioneTipoCertificato === 'NAVE'
     });
     dataPan.content.splice(index, 1);
}
```

from this function I get only 2 first elements with NAVE certificato.
This is not correct, I want all data with this certificato, so 3 elements, not 2.

Have you any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vanilla js here:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "codicePat": 93009428,
        "dataInizioAttivita": "1992-03-01",
        "dataCessazione": "0001-01-01",
        "descrizioneTipoCertificato": "NAVE",
    },
    {
        "codicePat": 93009429,
        "dataInizioAttivita": "1992-07-01",
        "dataCessazione": "0001-01-01",
        "descrizioneTipoCertificato": "NAVE",
    },
    {
        "codicePat": 93009430,
        "dataInizioAttivita": "1997-04-03",
        "dataCessazione": "0001-01-01",
        "descrizioneTipoCertificato": "COMANDATA",
    },
    {
        "codicePat": 93009431,
        "dataInizioAttivita": "1992-09-01",
        "dataCessazione": "1997-06-08",
        "descrizioneTipoCertificato": "NAVE",
    }    
]

const filtered = data.filter(item => item.descrizioneTipoCertificato === 'NAVE');

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `filter` on the array

```
 const newArr = oldArr.filter(item => item.descrizioneTipoCertificato == 'NAVE')
```

this will simply filter and return to a new array only the element that matches the condition